# JS files not updating in python dev server

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am running a local development server with python using VS as ide through
`python manage.py runserver`.
When I update and save JS files, the views in browser do not update (even restarting the server and PC). I refreshed the cache of the browser, however it does not resolve the issue. Anyone may know the root of the problem and/or possible solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using Chrome, try to delete Cached Images and Files and make sure to include the Time Range to "All Time". See if that helps.